# grid-area usage for whole websites

Tags: css, responsive-design, web

I have worked with web development for about a year at school now. I got a new teacher and she introduces a new CSS property called grid-area. I do understand how to use it, but not for complete websites. She could not give a good explanation.

I do not see any benefits in making the body a grid area and implement the different tags in these areas. So I'm asking here. What is the "theory behind" using the grid-area style property to better create websites and responsive design?

Comment: Hi,I recommend browsing [Grid by Example](https://gridbyexample.com/) - a web page by Rachel Andrew. You may find especially useful [Grab & Go Patterns](https://gridbyexample.com/patterns/)

Comment: @enxaneta will check it out! Thanks

Comment: Check it here also : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-area.asp

Comment: Just fount this amazing youtube about grid: very funny and so much to learn: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCZdCKjnBCs The grid-area thing begin at minute 30